# How can i pass data from an app to another one in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on creating a taxi app , I have two separated apps one for Client and for driver .
I want to send current locations of drivers to clients .I don't know how  I can   do that .

Comment: You can use push notification for that or your backend api just get lat long of  drivers and save into your database then you can send those lat long by api or push notification by backend Thank you

Comment: how you are passing data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a good option to use as your backend in this situation. It uses web sockets to automatically push data. You can use AngularFire to link Ionic with Firebase. (Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_73tsvj6OI)

Answer (score 1):

Hey @bambo so for your understanding it is not possible to transfer data from one app to another without connection, and in your case both of the app can be in distance where only internet will work. So you can use one of these methods:

- APIs for sending the data from one app and receiving it from other app.
- Send a notification direct to other app, which contain the data you want to send for ionic you can use PUSH cordova available on
  [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/).

Answer (score 0):

You can send or receive data through webIntent plugin provided by ionic.

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI          : 5.0.2 (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.4.0 (D:\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Command to install plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent
npm install --save @ionic-native/web-intent@4
```

> (Add 'Web-Intent' in provider)

Code To receive data:

```
import { WebIntent } from '@ionic-native/web-intent';

clickMe() {
    console.log('clicked')
    this.webIntent.getIntent().then((data) => {
      console.log('Success', data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }
```

Code To send data:

```
import { WebIntent } from '@ionic-native/web-intent';

    sendIntent() {
    console.log('sendIntent');

    const options = {
      action: 'com.example.myapplication',
      extras: {
        'data': 'Hello Android App'
      }
    }

    this.webIntent.sendBroadcast(options).then((succ) => {
      console.log('Success', succ);
    },
      err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: If there is a problem with cordova, then downgrade the node v-12 to v-10. Delete the node module from the project and run 'npm install' command to download dependencies. Hope everything will run fine.